# Read activated partition on Hive with Spark

Tags: apache-spark, hive, hdfs

I have a serious problem reading the activated partition in Spark with Dataframe

The problem is the following: I have 4 partition in Hive, in which only 2 partition are activated.

```
show partitions s__patriot.bi_fe__f_car_park;
```

result:
[image]

Now, if I count all records the result is 52141403; the result is correct, it works!

If I read the same folder in Spark, I read the wrong result:

```
val car_park = sqlContext.read.format("com.databricks.spark.avro").load("/data/swamp/patriot/bi_fe__f_car_park/")
```

[image]

The result of the count is different!
I investigated and I found the problem: in the folder /data/swamp/patriot/bi_fe__f_car_park/ there are 4 subfolders in which there are the data, but only 2 of these are actived.

[image]

The question is: is there a smart workaround to read "only" the activated partition with Spark?